Laser printer popping AFCI circuit breaker
I recently bought a Brother laser printer, plugged it into an outlet previously used for a laser printer, and it popped the house circuit breaker that the outlet is on. The circuit breaker is an AFCI type. According to Brother, it's a known problem, where their laser printers can trigger a false positive, causing AFCI breakers to pop unnecessarily. They have a printer firmware update that's supposed to fix it. Unfortunately, the update is offered for Windows and macOS, but not Linux, which I use (and I don't have ready access to a Windows or macOS computer).
Is there any kind of device I can plug between the printer and wall socket to prevent popping the breaker (the issue is related to arc fault sensing, not exceeding the current rating on the line)?
If not, is this problem specific to the design of Brother printers, or common to other brands of laser printers? I've been using laser printers for decades and this is the first time I've encountered the issue.

Microsoft offers free Windows 11 VMs that you could in theory use to install the firmware update.

@Ramhound, thanks for the suggestion. I've never done anything with VMs, so I'd need to get up to speed on it.

If the firmware utility does not exist for Linux there isn't anything we can do for you. My suggestion put something between the AFCI circuit like a UPS.

@Ramhound, that's where I was headed with the question. A UPS won't handle the load of a laser printer, but I thought someone might know whether a surge or noise suppressor, or some other power conditioning gadget, would deal with whatever it is that triggers the AFCI. I do plan to investigate your VM idea.


A UPS that’s plugged in absolutely could. You’ll have to run the printer long enough to update the firmware


I would not rely on a UPS. The problem is that due to energy regulations, most home and office UPSes in normal mode simply pass the current straight through, bypassing the transformer. This means there is no filtering. You could use a on-line (double-conversion) UPS, but by the time you get one, you're spending easily 5-10x the price of a new laser printer.

Possible DUP - https://superuser.com/questions/1571257/how-can-i-prevent-my-pc-from-tripping-the-arc-fault-breaker-when-turning-it-on  (Among other things, a commenter recons that the filtering in even a cheap UPS will filter the noise - which makes sense to me - although I've never come across an AFCI breaker)

@davidgo, I did more research. The Q you linked does relate to the same problem, but the answers aren't especially useful. Only VWFeature's answer addresses the Q. It isn't entirely accurate & the cheater plug is bad advice except as a diagnostic. Some EMI/RFI filters may help, but real-life reports show mixed results (depends on how much filtering in the right frequency range, how much noise, and how over-sensitive the breaker is). Each situation may require trying devices to see if they're adequate. In my case, the printer was plugged into a UPS surge/noise outlet when it popped the breaker.

Absolutely agree the cheater plug is bad advice except as a diagnostic... And even then its pretty sketch in my book.
